# Gunicorn: stuck at booting new workers

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I have a rather simple Flask application (using fastAPI) for loading a numpy array and defining some API endpoints.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('Loading texts')
texts = pd.read_csv('cleaned.csv')
logging.info('Loading embeddings')
embeddings = np.load('laser-2020-04-30.npy') # 3.7G
logging.info('Loading completed!')

# some API endpoints below...
```

I can run this app with pure `python3.7` without any issues. Also it runs fine while running vanilla gunicorn. The problem arises when running everything in a docker container (and using gunicorn). It seems to get stuck at loading the large numpy array and booting new workers.

```
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (1)
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2020-05-11 08:33:20 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 1 workers
INFO:root:Loading texts
INFO:root:Loading embeddings
[2020-05-11 08:33:35 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
INFO:root:Loading texts
INFO:root:Loading embeddings
[2020-05-11 08:33:51 +0000] [29] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29
INFO:root:Loading texts
INFO:root:Loading embeddings
[2020-05-11 08:34:05 +0000] [40] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 40
INFO:root:Loading texts
INFO:root:Loading embeddings
[2020-05-11 08:34:19 +0000] [51] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 51
INFO:root:Loading texts
INFO:root:Loading embeddings
[2020-05-11 08:34:36 +0000] [62] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 62
```

I set the number of workers to 1 and increased the timeout to 900 seconds. However, it boots new workers every 10-15 sec.

The command of running the application in my `Dockerfile` looks like following

```
CMD ["gunicorn","-b 0.0.0.0:8080", "main:app", "--timeout 900", "--log-level", "debug", "--workers", "1", "--graceful-timeout", "900"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I simply [increased the available amount of RAM that the docker container](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#resources) could use. The default was 2G on my MacBook 2019 installation of docker. Since the numpy array was 3.7G this is why it could not load it.

```
docker run -m=8g -t my_docker
```