# Stuck on "Booting worker with pid: 7" while deploying a service in Kubernetes using Docker image, What seems to be the problem here?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

So basically i am trying to deploy a service in Kubernetes cluster using a DockerFile, after so many attempts i am still stuck with the same error message **Booting worker with pid: 7** on loop, without any exit code i.e.

```
[2023-01-11 09:22:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-01-11 09:22:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2023-01-11 09:22:48 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2023-01-11 09:22:48 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

here is my Docker image:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

I am really not getting where am i wrong, any leads would be super helpful..!!

Comment: That Dockerfile seems routine to me.  The log messages seem fine too, and I might even expect the GUnicorn process is serving requests.  What's going wrong?  Cam you make requests via a Kubernetes Service?  Do you need either parts of your application source or the Kubernetes YAML as part of a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below possible Solutions :**

**I)Memory Issue :**

1)Try adding more resources (requests & limits) under the container - may need more memory.

2)Try to increase the available amount of RAM that the docker container, Please see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725704/gunicorn-stuck-at-booting-new-workers) for more info and also `Clear the Cache` : log in the console of the `backend` container, then issue the command `bench --site SITE_NAME clear-cache`.

**II)From Gunicorn side :**

1)**[AsyncIO Workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#asyncio-workers) :** The worker `gthread` is a threaded worker. It accepts connections in the main loop, accepted connections are added to the thread pool as a connection job. On keepalive connections are put back in the loop waiting for an event. If no event happens after the keep alive timeout, the connection is closed.

2)`To use the inotify reloader, you must have the inotify package installed.` Please check [Gunicorn settings debugging](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#debugging) for more information.

3)Create a Gunicorn config file using `configmap` and mount it to the web pod. Make sure `bind` is passed via config file, not through `args`. Please go through the [Write Kubernetes manifests for python flask app](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/write-kubernetes-manifests-for-python-flask-app-aa9e3bee710b) for more information.

Comment: Increasing the memory worked for my case..!! Thanks for the help..!! :)

Comment: I’m having the same trouble, but having trouble changing the memory settings on the container. I’ve been building and running my docker file with `docker compose up -d —-build`, and when I try to run it with `docker run {image name}` it just creates a new image within my container instead of running my existing one, so I’m having a hard time setting the memory flag… any ideas what I’m doing wrong?